# webapi post request - HttpActionContext.ActionArguments has no value

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I'm trying to make a WebAPi post request of an object, using postman.
The HttpPost method exists in the controller.
The problem is that the HttpActionContext.ActionArguments has the name of the (object) instance parameter in the method as a key, but has no value.
Not really figuring out why it happens.
I'm doing the same thing successfully with a different controller, post method and object

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason for that - it turns out that the binding is done using the object constructor - there's a need in default constructor which was missing there !